# Manually install an extension in ReSharper 9.2

Tags: resharper

I have a very restrictive firewall at work, that block the resharper extension manager. Is there a way to manually install the Postfix Templates plugin?

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can!

First, download the extension (a NuGet .nupkg file) from the following url:

> https://resharper-plugins.jetbrains.com/api/v2/package/ReSharper.Postfix.R90

Put it in a directory. Next, go to **ReSharper Options > Extension Manager**, and add the directory to the sources list.

You'll now be able to see the extension listed in the Extensions Manager.

Comment: Just one thing, you need to be logged in to see the download link.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing on my build server using the Resharper Command line. Now that my nupkg file is downloaded, how can I install it (without Visual Studio) so I can use it with the CL ? See my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42092576/how-to-install-extension-for-resharper-command-line-tools.

Comment: Got the answer ! Please follow the link to my question if you're curious.