# How to install extension for Resharper command-line tools

Tags: command-line, continuous-integration, resharper

We're currently using the Resharper command-line tool 2016.3 on our CI build server to inspect code for issues at build time. It's working pretty well but I still have an issue and I can't find any proper documentation on that : how do I install and configure an extension using the command line. For example, I want to add the Cyclomatic complexity extension to my analysis. [Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.3/InspectCode.html) said to use the -x switch with the name of the extension (PowerToys.CyclomaticComplexity). The code inspection runs but the complexity warning aren't included in my result file, probably because the extension isn't installed on my build server which make sense. I don't have VS installed on my build machine (and I would prefer not to have to) so how can I install the extension "manually" ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command line tools in 2016.3 don't currently fully support loading extensions. [This comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-436208#comment=27-1667146) in the issue tracker has some steps that might be able to support - basically put the .nupkg of the extension in the product folder. YMMV.

Comment: Thanks. The link you sent wasn't the complete solution but gave me the missing piece of the solution. For the record, what I had to do was :  to copy de .nupkg of the extension in the command-line folder, clear the solution cache (so all the files are reanalyzed) then put the name of the extension in the command with the -x switch (ex : -x="PowerToys.CyclomaticComplexity"). After that, worked like a charm !